# PHP CodeIgniter Pagination link broken

Tags: php, codeigniter, pagination, initialization, broken-links

```
public function index($page = 0) {
    $this->load->library('pagination');
    $conf = array(
        'total_rows' => 11,
        'base_url' => 'localhost/admin/product/index',
        'per_page' => 10,
        'use_page_numbers' => false
    );
    $this->pagination->initialize($conf);
    $this->load->view('product/index');
}
```

In view

```
<?php echo $this->pagination->create_links(); ?>
```

In the first page it work correctly. When I click on the page 2 link, it only display ONE product, this was correct, but the pagination links for current page still in page ONE. Suppose this should be page TWO.

which part I did wrong?

Comment: Well, the pagination class is not encrypted

Comment: I realize that my uri_segment is 4. However, the default pagination uri_segment is 3. Thus just do this: $conf['uri_segment'] = 4;

Answer (score 0):

Well, the pagination class uses "per_page" in the query string.  So, you have to divide that number by 10 (in your case) and add 1 to get the real page number, i.e.:

```
localhost/product/index (page 1)
localhost/product/index?per_page=10 (page 2)
localhost/product/index?per_page=20 (page 3)
...
localhost/product/index?per_page={10n) (page n+1)
```

This is useful to use directly in the database limit clause:

```
$this->db->limit(10, $this->input->get('per_page'))...
```

I think that's why CI chose to do it that way....

Comment: CI_Pagination Object
(
    [base_url] => http://localhost/project/admin/product/index
    [prefix] => 
    [suffix] => 
    [total_rows] => 11
    [per_page] => 10
    [num_links] => 2
    ...
}

This is the configuration of Pagination object. I still cannot find out the problem.

Comment: I had found the problem, the answer I had commented above. Thanks for your answer anyway.

Comment: That's frustrating.  Didn't realize you were using segments and not query strings. Oh well.  Upvote for the effort? ;)